# Problems while deleting duplicated values in a list of dicts?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a dictionary like this (its actually a json):

```
[
      {
            "val": "regards",
            "example": ["kind regards","regards", "kind regards"]
      },
      {
            "val": "Greets",
            "example": ["Hello ","Hi","Hello", "Hello"]
      }
]
```

How can I remove the duplicated strings in `example` key? I tried to:

In:

```
def remove_dups(a_dict):
    return {k:sorted(set(j),key=j.keys) for k,j in a_dict.items()}

with open('../a_json.json','r') as fa:
    a = json.load(fa)
    pprint(list(map(remove_dups,a)))
```

Out:

```
[
      {
            "val": ['r','e','g','a','r','d','s'],
            "example": ["regards", "kind regards"]
      },
      {
            "val": ['G','r','e','e','t','s'],
            "example": ["Hi","Hello"]
      }
]
```

Nevertheless, the `val` key is transformed into a list of strings. How can I leave `val` and just remove duplicates from `example`?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your output. `j.keys` should trigger an `AttributeError` because the list or string `j` has no attribute `keys`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a combination of `set` and `list` with `isinstance` in the comprehension:

```
>>> d
{'val': 'Greets', 'example': ['Hello ', 'Hi', 'Hello', 'Hello']}
>>> {k: list(set(v)) if isinstance(v, list) else v for k, v in d.items()}
{'val': 'Greets', 'example': ['Hello', 'Hi', 'Hello ']}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: @J.Doe, and welcome to SO. You may consider reading this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: @U9-Forward I was waiting.... cant accept now because need time before the answer is posted..